# asn1 file creation giving error for big file size

Tags: java

I am creating asn1 format file with file name,file content type and filedata when ever i import big  size file it is giving error of java heap space.

```
ASN1EncodableVector seq = new ASN1EncodableVector(); 
seq.add(new DERTaggedObject(false, 0, new DERSequence(new DERUTF8String(new File(filePath).getName())))); 

  seq.add(new DERTaggedObject(false, 1, new DERSequence(new DERUTF8String(fileContentType))));
        seq.add(new DEROctetString(fileDataInBytes));
        ASN1InputStream tempstream=new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesArray));
        ASN1Sequence seq1=(ASN1Sequence)tempstream.readObject();
        seq.add((ASN1Encodable) seq1);
   byte[] filebytes= new DERSequence(seq).getEncoded();//On this line i am getting error of heap size
  FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(fileName) , filebytes);
```

Is there any alternative way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing and hence flushing the entire contents of your byte[] at once when you use the command:-

```
 FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(fileName) , filebytes);
```

1)You need to reduce the size of `filebytes` and keep flushing it regularly,say in loops. You need to determine how much byte[] you want to keep in memory before writing the next set of byte[].In this way,you can manage your heap size.
Use

```
public static void writeByteArrayToFile(File file,
                            byte[] data,
                            boolean append)
                                     throws IOException
```

This would append the data in the file

2)You can set the inital and max heap size using Xms and Xmx option ( though I owuld not suggest this)

Comment: thanks for reply can i append byte by byte in file. can you explain your code?  how to embed in  file ?

Comment: yes.. you can do that.You have to make sure that the size of byte[] is not very high and can be managed by the JVM in its heap.You can also check the overloaded methods of writeByteArrayToFile.It has offset and length parameters to determine the length of byte and position

Comment: My problem is that only i have to allow file with bigger size. and that why byte[] is becoming very high.

that why i am getting error on this line  byte[] filebytes= new DERSequence(seq).getEncoded(); 

encoding calculating more bytes that why heap size is becoming full.